# Occupation (or particle) number operator. Eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

https://homepage.univie.ac.at/reinhold.bertlmann/pdfs/T2_Skript_Ch_5.pdf

Help me please. I made a screen (below) from the article above and highlighted what I did not understand.
Why is it true?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXpVV.png)

Answer (score 1):

The operator $N$ works like this

$$
N \psi_{} =  \psi_{} \tag{1}
$$

Which you can read as: If I apply $N$ to a state, I get the label of state times the state (more technically, $\psi_{}$ is an eigenvector of $N$ with eigenvalue $$).

In your problem you have

$$
N(a^\dagger\psi_\nu) = (\nu + 1)(a^\dagger \psi_\nu) \tag{2}
$$

If you compare this with (1) you will conclude that

$$
a^\dagger\psi_\nu \sim \psi_{\nu + 1}
$$

Comment: I will ask in another way. Why can't one eigenvalue correspond to two linearly independent vectors? In this situation.

Comment: @ИванПетров You mean something like $a^{\dagger} \psi_{\nu} = (\nu + 1)( \psi^{(1)}_{\nu+1} + \psi^{(2)}_{\nu+1} )$?

Comment: I mean that a^\dagger\psi_\nu and \psi_{\nu + 1} may be linearly independent. Why not?

Comment: @ИванПетров And have the same eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, the same eigenvalue

Comment: @ИванПетров I see. Turns out the operator $N$ is not degenerate (e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23028/proof-that-the-one-dimensional-simple-harmonic-oscillator-is-non-degenerate)) which means that for each label $\nu$ there's only one state $\psi_\nu$. So you cannot have multiple linearly independent eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue, just one

Comment: @ИванПетров No problem. Your original question does not reflect the discussion we just had. I strongly advice you edit it, so that it includes the actual question you have, it will help future users with similar questions. Plus a simple 'please help' with no other explanation usually is frowned upon in this site